# How to upload file with vue component and laravel controller [Axios]

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, controller, upload

I want to upload an image file with vue component to laravel controller. My problem happens when I click submit button name/description/address is saved but the image name not save

I want to save the image name to my database but if($request->hasFile('id_image')) always return false

Can you tell me about syntax to solve this solution?

this is create.vue

```
       <form action="/listorgs" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>name_org:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="org.name_org">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>picture:</label>
            <input
              type="file"
              @change="onFileChange"
              name="name_image"
              id="id_image"
              class="inputFile"
            >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>description:</label>
            <textarea
              class="form-control mb-2"
              rows="5"
              v-model="org.description"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>address:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="org.address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="addNewOrg()">Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

in export default

```
data() {
    return {
      org: {
        name_org: "",
        description: "",
        address: "",
        image: ""
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNewOrg() {
      axios
        .post("/api/listorgs", this.org)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          if (response.data.etat) {
            this.org = {
              name_org: response.data.etat.name_org,
              description: response.data.etat.description,
              address: response.data.etat.address,
              picture: response.data.etat.image
            };
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("errors: ", error);
        });
        console.log(this.image);
    },
    onFileChange(e) {
      let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length) return;
      this.createImage(files[0]);
    },
    createImage(file) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => {
        this.org.image = e.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

This is my controller

```
$listorg=new ListOrg();
$listorg->name_org=$request->get('name_org');
$listorg->description=$request->get('description');
$listorg->address=$request->get('address');
if($request->hasFile('name_image')){
    $listorg->picture= $request->image->store('images');
}
$listorg->save();
return response()->json($listorg);
```

It say
[image]

Comment: you will need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` attribute for file uploads

Comment: I already try it but it not work. But I think it important I will update in code

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript references an 'image' field and your field is named 'id_image'?

Sorry, I can't comment yet (score), but maybe try sticking to a convention of some kind?

Try just dumping & dying the full request in your controller method.

Might give you a good clue on what's wrong.

Comment: in controller I try dd($request->all()); but it not show me anythings.

Comment: Sorry, vue doesn't let you do dd from the controller (I don't think), my bad.

Try putting {{ var_dump($request) }} in your template and pass the request data from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

$listorg->picture.

If I am right, the data returned from the controller does not have image property. 
try console.log(this.picture);